# wordpress multisite logout of all network sites simultaneously

Tags: wordpress, networking, logout, simultaneous

i have a wordpress network (multisite) setup that i would like help coming up with a solution for a problem that seems to be core to the nature of wordpress multisite.

problem:
when i log into the main network site (mysite.com/member/) access to all of the other network sites is automatically authenticated and gratned.

the issue is when logging out of one of the network sites, the wp_logout() function only seems to affect the existing site being viewed.

for example: logging out of mysite.com/network-site/ it in fact does log out, however navigating back to mysite.com/member/ shows the user as still logged in and authenticated with full access.

question:
what can i do to program the wp_logout() function so that all sites in the network have the authentication cookie trashed/removed thus actually logging the user out of all network sites?

thank you for your help!
andrew

Answer (score 1):

> problem: when i log into the main network site (mysite.com/member/) access to all of the 
>   other network sites is automatically authenticated and gratned.

Just remove the user you are using for the parent site from all the other sites.

You can define how wordpress handles the authentication cookie in your main `wp-config.php`. What we need to do here, is to force WordPress to follow the correct cookie path. This can be done by adding this to your wp-config.php file located in your WordPress installation root directory:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Comment: the user is not active on the network site -- only on the "main" site.

also, i already have wp-config.php setup as you indicated above.

is there a way for me to force the removal of the authentication cookie?

in searching the actual browser cookies, it is still present and active after logging out of one of the network sites.

Comment: has anyone else had this problem? more and more i am seeing this as a fundamental wordpress multisite bug.

Comment: No, never seen this. The admin of the multisite installation is not automatically admin of the subsites; a deleted cookie logs you out. I tested this minutes ago - either my instalation is somewhere corrupt, or yours :-)

Comment: right, in my case i have added/created a super-admin.

what i am referencing however is a registered user, not an admin.

would navigating the site be helpful here?